# Rails validation dependent on associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

So I'm writing code in which we need to issue refunds.  I wrote a refund validator that checks to ensure that the refund is not for more than the original charge.  However, in my specs I came to the realization that the associated charge isnt' present yet.  Using FactorGirl.  How can I make something like this work?

Validator

```
class RefundValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value <= record.charge.amount
      record.errors[:attribute] << "is greater than original charge"
    end
  end
end
```

Validation

```
validates :amount, refund: true
```

Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :refund do
    association :client
    association :charge
    amount 99
  end
end
```

Spec

```
context 'validations' do
  %i(client_id therapist_id appointment_id booking_id value).each do |attr|
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of attr }
  end
  it { is_expected.to validate_numericality_of(:value).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(0).is_less_than_or_equal_to(5) }
end
```

Error (i get this for all 4 attributes in the presence spec, not just client_id):

```
1) Refund validations should require client_id to be set
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of attr }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/validators/refund_validator.rb:3:in `validate_each'
 # ./spec/models/refund_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried explicitly creating the Factory model with a charge factory explicitly specified, but to no avail.  No clue what's going on.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- I would change `unless x <= y` to `if x > y` for the sake of readability
- In any case, you should use `record.try(:charge).try(:amount)` instead of `record.charge.amount` to prevent `NoMethodError`s in your validator.

Let me know if that fixes the problem already.